# How to remove maven artifcat completely from SpringSource?

Tags: maven, artifact

I have a local maven repository and installed a custom artifact. It works if i reference it in other projects. But now i want to use a server for a "own maven repository". If i delete the artifact from the local maven repository, i assumed that the project will not build when i do a maven clean and maven force update dependencies. The artifact cannot be found under .m2/ but Spring Source Tool Suite still can add the artifact to new Java Projects. Create New Java Project -> Edit Pom -> Maven Artifact is added, even if i deleted it from local repository .m2/ . How is this possible and how can i delete it completely, to be able to test if now all dependencies are updated from my server with the .m2/settings.xml configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your repository is just a directory/file structure. Go to your local repo, find the path (the group id is the path), and delete from the place where you start to see version numbers. When you rebuild, the artifact should be downloaded/replaced from your server/repo.

Comment: i have already done this, i also closed Spring Source Tool Suite and opened it again, and it still found the dependency.. even if i create a new java project and declare a this dependency there, it will include it.. so Spring Source Tool Suite has another layer of dependency repository cache?